# miniupnpd.confの場所が分からない

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, network

raspberry piにminiupnpを入れ
upnpc -a 192.168.0.27 80 80 tcp
upnpc -a 192.168.0.27 800 800 tcp(800は適当な番号)
として追加しupnpc -lで確認すると
 0 TCP    80->192.168.0.1:80    'libminiupnpc' '' 0
 1 TCP 800->192.168.0.27:800 'libminiupnpc' '' 0
となってなぜか80番ポートだけ正しく追加出来ない
80番だけはなぜか192.168.0.1にリダイレクトする設定になってしまう
他のポート番号は192.168.0.27にリダイレクトできている
なのでconfファイルを書き換えようと思ったが/etc/ないにminiupnpd.confがない・・・
/usr/local/etc/もなくfindで調べたがなかった
自分はapt-getでインストールしてます
upnpcのconfファイルまたはそれに準じるファイルの場所がわかる方いますか？

Answer (score 2):

もうポートが使われてるんでは無いでしょうか。raspbianなら`netstat -pln`で80番が何に使われているか確認できると思います。
あとconfigは`/usr/share/miniupnpd`だと‌​思いますが、800番は大丈夫なのでupn‌​pcは正しく動いて、80がダメなのには理‌​由があると思うので極力upnpcでやった‌​ほうがいいと思います。